# In welchem Teil Deutschlands sagt man "ratzen"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, dialect

> Ich möchte heute Nacht bei meiner Mutter ratzen.

Wo in Deutschland sagt man "ratzen" und haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung wie "pennen" ?

Comment: Ich kenne es hauptsächlich als _**ein**ratzen_ und sonst eher in Zeitformen, die das Partizip _geratzt_ verwenden. Es ist wohl nicht verwandt mit _Ratzefummel_ ‚Radiergummi‘. _Penner_ ‚Obdachloser‘, _Penne_ ‚Schule‘ und _Pennäler_ ‚Schüler‘ dürften hingegen mit _pennen_ verwandt sein, welches ich am häufigsten in _**ver**pennen_ höre. Der online frei verfügbare [Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de) listet leider zu ‚schlafen‘ bisher keine regionale Verteilung.

Comment: Zu Crissov's Kommentar fällt mir noch der Begriff *Ratzekahl* (=gänzlich leer) ein, der z.B. ausdrücken soll, dass gar nichts mehr übrig geblieben ist.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: *ratzekahl* kannte ich noch nicht, dafür das offenbar gleichbedeutende *ratzeputz*.

Comment: Laut Wissen.de ist die Wortherkunft von "[Pennen]" wahrscheinlich jiddisch von "pannai" = "müßig"
   http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/pennen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Duden online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ratzen_schlafen) markiert das Wort in der Bedeutung *fest und lange schlafen* als umgangssprachlich ohne besonderen regionalen Bezug. Das entspricht auch meinem Eindruck. Regionale Einschränkungen sind dennoch naheliegend, weil das Wort laut Duden von "schlafen wie ein Ratz" abgeleitet ist, wobei *Ratz* hier ein altes und [in Bayern und Österreich noch gebräuchliches](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f05c/) Wort für *Ratte* ist, das in diesem Fall aber wohl für *Siebenschläfer* steht.

Von meinem Vater kenne ich den verwandten Spruch "Schlafratze, runter von der Matratze!" Hier hat sich wohl die alte Form *der Ratz / die Ratze* gehalten, weil sich *Ratte* nicht reimen würde.

Comment: Ich sehe das auch als ursprünglich süddeutschen/bayrischen Ausdruck, der inzwischen allgemein verbreitet ist.

Answer (score 6):

Über die regionale Verbreitung kann ich nichs genaues sagen, aber über den Gebrauch:

*[Ratzen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ratzen_schlafen)* beschreibt den unmittelbaren Vorgang des (tief) Schlafens.
Während man formal alle Tempora bilden kann, würde ich *ratzen* nicht für geplanten Aktivitäten benutzen, also nicht:

> <del>Ich will heute bei meiner Mutter ratzen.</del>

Genauso wenig sehe ich eine Substantivierung  <del>das Ratzen</del>  oder Gebrauch des Partizip I <del>der ratzende Bruder</del>, aber das beruht auf meinem Sprachgefühl.

*[Pennen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pennen)* ist ähnlich umgangssprachlich, aber ohne die oben genannten Einschränkungen.

Bitte beachten, dass *pennen* eine erweiterte/übertragene Bedeutung von *schlafen* haben kann nämlich auch *unaufmerksam sein* und *Geschlechtsverkehr mit jmd. haben*, die *ratzen* nicht hat.
Regionale Jugendsprache (mindestens SW Deutschland) dagegen benutzt *verratzt* als *abgetragen, zerrissen (Kleidung)* und übertragen auch als Adjektiv für den Träger derselben.